# Show a set of polynomial functions is a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $T$ be the set of all polynomial functions from $\Bbb{Z}_3 \to \Bbb{Z}_3$.
Show that $T$ is a ring.
Show that $T$ is a finite ring with zero divisors.
(Hint: consider $x + 1$ and $x^2 + 2x$.) Show that $T$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_3[x]$.

To show it is a ring, I must show the set is closed under subtraction and multiplication.

To show it is a finite ring with zero divisors, I just multiply two polynomials together such that it has the same degree or less. Because it has roots such that the polynomial equals zero, the set $T$ has a zero divisor.

e.g. $(x+1)(x)(x+2) = (x^2+3x+2)(x) = x^3 + 2x$ implying $3x = 0$.

Also, what is the difference between the set of polynomial functions of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $Z_3[x]$? They look the same in notation.

Comment: For the last question, one difference is that there are only $27$ polynomial functions, but infinitely many polynomials.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I added an example, is it correct and the reasoning/inference from it?

Comment: The set of polynomial functions is actually a *homomorphic image* of the formal polynomial ring. (Also, in order to show that $x(x+1)(x+2)$ is the zero polynomial function, it suffices to observe that all three elements of $Z_3$ are zeros of it.)

Comment: If all the elements of $\Bbb{Z}_3$ are zeros of a polynomial $p(x)$, then that means that the polynomial function $p:\Bbb{Z}_3\to\Bbb{Z}_3$ is constant **mapping** zero. This happens, for example, for the polynomial $p(x)=x^3-x$. But $p(x)$ is **not** the zero element of the ring $\Bbb{Z}_3[x]$. One reason for that is that this polynomial is cubic, but the zero polynomial has degree zero (or $-\infty$ depending on how *degree* is defined in your textbook.

Comment: In other words, the elements of $\Bbb{Z}_3[x]$ are **formal** polynomials, i.e. sums of the form $f(x)=\sum_ia_ix^i$ where $i$ takes finitely many non-negative integers as its values, and $a_i\in \Bbb{Z}_3$. Here we say that two polynomials are the same polynomial, say $f(x)$ above is equal to $g(x)=\sum_i b_ix^i$, if and only if $a_i=b_i$ for all $i$. This definition is agnostic to whether the two polynomials take the same value everywhere.